# Age range on age range in WHERE to heavy - POSTGRES

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 columns in the database for events.

1. agelow (int)
2. agehigh (int)

How it's structured:

- `agehigh` is being used for "and under" which is represented by 0 in the column
- the high age is placed in the agelow column
- The "and over" is represented by 99 and is not a problem since it has the agehigh and the agelow in the right columns.
- all ages are represented with 99 in both columns.

I am trying to write a WHERE that can pull all event ages if no ages are passed in but also need to be able to pull events just for one age passed in or for an age range passed in. The age range is making this a big headache.

### Example

If I pass in agelow 5 and agehigh 15, I would need to grab all events that are

1. available for anyone from 5 up to 15 which includes the "5 and under", "5 and up", "15 and under" and all ages.

Here is the WHERE part:

```
WHERE
((events.age_low >= agelow AND events.age_high <= agehigh) OR
 (events.age_low <= agelow AND events.age_high >= agehigh) OR
 (events.age_low <= agelow /* LOW (99 for all) */ AND events.age_high >= agelow /* LOW (99 for all) */) OR
 (events.age_low <= agelow /* LOW (99 for all) */ AND events.age_high = 99 /* DEFAULT 99 */) OR
 (events.age_low >= agelow /* LOW (99 for all) */ AND events.age_high = 0 /* DEFAULT 0 */) OR 
 (events.age_high >= agehigh /* HIGH (0 for all) */ AND events.age_low <= agehigh /* HIGH (0 for all) */) OR 
 (events.age_low >= agehigh /* HIGH (0 for all) */ AND events.age_high = 0 /* DEFAULT 0 */) OR 
 (events.age_low <= agehigh /* HIGH (0 for all) */ AND events.age_high = 99 /* DEFAULT 99 */) OR  
 (events.age_low = 99 AND events.age_high = 99));
```

Here is a small selection of the age columns:

```
CREATE TABLE events(age_low,age_high)
AS VALUES
  (  99 ,  99 ),
  (   3 ,  12 ),
  (   1 ,   6 ),
  (   5 ,   0 ),
  (  99 ,  99 ),
  (  99 ,  99 ),
  (  99 ,  99 ),
  (   5 ,  11 ),
  (   5 ,   0 ),   -- this is 5 and below
  (  16 ,  99 ),   -- this is 16 and up
  (   1 ,   4 ),
  (  13 ,  18 ),
  (  99 ,  99 ),   -- this is all ages
  (   5 ,   0 ),
  (  99 ,  99 );
```

Comment: What should happen if you put in ages 5-15, and there's an event for ages 10-20. Should it be excluded, as not everyone in the age range could attend?

Comment: Also - can you specify a value greater than 2 digits (e.g., ages "100 and up", or "10-110"?

Comment: If any age from 5 to 15 matches the range given in the database age_low to age_high range it needs to be included. So 10-20 should show up in the results.

Comment: the age values in the database are 0-18 and 99 and will not go past 2 digits

Comment: How large is this table?

Comment: currently 200000 rows and growing

Comment: @MarcUsa If I can make a suggestion, delete half of that question and simply show us what you want get from that sample data with a given a query. Your explanation is pretty lacking outside of the sample data and the failed attempt is also not useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to wrap `greatest` and `least` to assist this. We can use this to iron out the oddities

1. `5,0` being five and under. That should really be `0,5` if there was any level of sanity.
2. That `99,99` is all ages. Here if the lower bound is `99` we set that to `-1` just be sure it's all ages.

Code,

```
CREATE FUNCTION normalize_query_range(start int, finish int)
RETURNS int4range
AS
$$
  SELECT int4range(
    CASE WHEN least(start,finish) = 99 THEN -1 ELSE least(start,finish) END
    , greatest(start,finish)
  );
$$ LANGUAGE sql
IMMUTABLE;
```

Now, we can easily do this using the [range operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html) for `@>` contains, and `&&` overlaps.

```
SELECT age_low,age_high
FROM events
WHERE normalize_query_range(age_low,age_high) && int4range(5,15);
```

And, even better, creating an index will speed this up.

```
CREATE INDEX ON events
  USING gist(normalize_query_range(age_low, age_high));
```

Comment: Testing this as well, first results show speed improvement :) Having to read up on INDEX ON with USING GIST. Have never used this before. Learning so much. Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: When I have one age only like 5 it fails to return any rows.

SELECT age_low,age_high
FROM events
WHERE normalize_query_range(age_low,age_high) && int4range(5,5);

Comment: @MarcUsa you have to use `@>` to query element in range.  `normalize_query_range(age_low,age_high) @> 5;` A range can only overlap with another range, however it contains (fully) any element in the range.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to improve readability would be to use a CTE to add a couple of calculated columns..  However, this approach could also be slow, depending on the size of the table..  But it would look something like this

```
WITH true_ages AS (
  SELECT
    <cols>,
    CASE WHEN age_high < age_low THEN age_high -- handle case of 'x and below'
         WHEN age_low = 99 and age_high = 99 THEN 0 -- handle case of 'all ages'
         ELSE age_low END as true_low,
    CASE WHEN age_low < age_high and age_high = 99 THEN 999 -- handle case of 'x and above'
         WHEN age_low = 99 and age_high = 99 THEN 999 -- handle case of 'all ages'
         ELSE age_high END as true_high
  FROM <table>
) SELECT
  <cols>
FROM true_ages
WHERE <target_age> BETWEEN true_low and true_high;
```

You could potentially add some WHERE clause in the CTE to reduce the result set initially, but that might add unnecessary complexity.

Comment: I'll test it. Currently on the 200k rows my messy query is hitting close to 1 second in time. I feel like my query being so messy is making it so slow :(

Comment: Your query should be pretty efficient, actually, despite the messiness.  It'll do a full table scan, I assume, but it'll be able to determine which records to keep and toss very quickly.  With a CTE, it might do the equivalent of 2 full table scans.  Depends on how intelligent the query planner is about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two number ranges, aStart to aEnd and bStart to bEnd, then they overlap if:

- aStart <= bEnd, **and**
- aEnd >= bStart

In reality, you just have three cases:

- all ages (99-99)
- "and under" (X - 0)
- regular, plus "and over" (X - Y)

For "and over", Y happens to be 99, instead of 0-18. Since the values still represent a valid range, that doesn't need to be a special case.

So, this WHERE clause should work:

```
WHERE 
      -- standarad range, or "and over"
      (    events.agelow <= agehigh
       AND events.agehigh >= agelow
      )
   OR -- "and under"
      (    events.agehigh = 0
       AND events.agelow >= agelow
      )
   OR -- all ages
      (    events.agelow = 99
       AND events.agehigh = 99
      )
```

Note: only tested mentally, not via actual code.

Comment: Testing this, so far it looks like it is giving the right results.

Comment: The mental testing did let me correct a `<=` to ` >=`, so I actually wasn't kidding about that. Still, you can stare at a sign, andstill manage to read it backwards - the computer, fortunately enough, manages not to make that sort of mistake.